# Delphi TRESTRequest gets Access Violation when attempting TRESTRequest.AddBody()

Tags: json, rest, delphi

I am working with a Delphi (10.2.2) Client app that calls API functions on a Delphi REST Server (WebModule). At this point I have 10s of these types of API calls that perform all relevant HTTP verbs (POST, GET, PUT, DELETE) and they all work fine, EXCEPT for calls where I need to upload a JSON object for INSERT/EDITs on the Server. I am not sure what I am doing wrong, so if anyone could look at my attempt and let me know what I'm missing?

```
var
  REQ : TRESTRequest;
  RESP : TRESTResponse;
  NewPL : TJSONObject;
  strOut : String;
begin
  try
    REQ := TRESTRequest.Create(Application);
    RESP := TRESTResponse.Create(Application);
    REQ.Response := RESP;
    REQ.Resource := 'packlist';
    REQ.Client := DM1.RESTClient;
    REQ.Method := TRESTRequestMethod.rmPOST;

   //Create JSON from UI
   NewPL := TJSONObject.Create;
   NewPL.AddPair('PL_NO', edtPLNo.Text);
   NewPL.AddPair('PL_DATE', edtPLDate.Text);
   NewPL.AddPair('SHIP_NO', edtShipmentNo.Text);
   NewPL.AddPair('SHIPPER', memShipper.Text);
   NewPL.AddPair('CONSIGNEE', memConsignee.Text);
   NewPL.AddPair('VEHICLE_REG_NO', edtVehicleRegNo.Text);
   NewPL.AddPair('ETD', DateTimeToStr(dateETD.Date));
   NewPL.AddPair('ETA', DateTimeToStr(dateETA.Date));
   NewPL.AddPair('TOTAL_QTY', edtTotalQty.Text);
   NewPL.AddPair('TOTAL_WEIGHT', edtTotalWeight.Text);
   NewPL.AddPair('TOTAL_VOLUME', edtTotalVol.Text);
   if chkPLComplete.Checked then
     NewPL.AddPair('COMPLETE', '1')
   else
     NewPL.AddPair('COMPLETE', '0');
   NewPL.AddPair('SUPPLIER_NO', edtSuppNo5.Text);
   NewPL.AddPair('DEBTOR_ACC_NO', '');
   NewPL.AddPair('WAYBILL_NO', edtWaybillNo.Text);
   strOut := NewPL.ToString;

   REQ.AddBody(NewPL); //AV occurs here
   REQ.Execute;
   DisplayPL(NewPL);

 finally
   REQ.DisposeOf;
   RESP.DisposeOf;
 end;
end;
```

I am sure I have made a mistake somewhere, that I keep overlooking...

Comment: Creating a TJSONObject and then leaking it by overwriting the reference doesn't make sense. You don't show enough code to see other problems - no definition for NewPL or PackListFromUI.

Comment: Hi Brian - you are correct. I overwrote an Object reference. Instead, I have now replaced the function (PackListFromUI) with the actual code that creates and populates the TJSONObject (NewPL). I have now edited my question accordingly

Comment: The code you have provided is far from [**minimal** reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). People just can't copy your snippet and try it out on their own. Anyway, what prevents you from using `DM1.RESTClient.PostEntity<TJSONObject>('packlist', NewPL)`?

Comment: This post needs a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. You've not provided one yet. Please [edit] to do so, and add the relevant information in the post instead of in comments.